# Use vodafone easy-box umts-stick slot for usb network drive

Tags: usb, router, network-drive

I own a Vodafone DSL-EasyBox 602 as router for my home wlan. This device includes a USB-UMTS-Stick Slot for mobile internet. I don't use this USB slot and was wondering, if I could use this USB Slot for running a network HD. In the extras section of my routers page, it says, that this slot is for use of an USB-UMTS-Stick, but I guess it should somehow be possible to access the file system as well?

Has anyone already experience with this or something similar? If not, could someone briefly outline, why it is most likely not possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not!